# SQL Increment field from values X to Y

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a field to increment by @increment between two variables @start and @end, resetting at @end and beginning again with @start and continuing for all rows in the table.

If

```
@start = .06 
@end = .10
@increment = .02
```

Then I'm looking for something like:

```
1 .06
2 .08
3 .10
4 .06
5 .08
6 .10
```

I've tried using Row_Number() with a modulo, but it doesn't work after the first reset.

Comment: how many such rows do you have to generate?

Comment: Please post the code from your attempt with row_number

Comment: @vkp the number of rows is dependent on other fields in the table that are variable. It basically just needs to continue until the end like Row_Number() would

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select 1 as n, cast(@start as decimal(10, 2)) as val
      union all
      select n + 1, cast(val + @increment as decimal(10, 2))
      from cte
      where val + @increment <= @end
     )
select * 
from cte cross join
     t;
```

You need to change the max recursion option, if you want more than 100 rows in the output.

EDIT:

I may have completely misunderstood the question.  Perhaps you have a table with six rows and you want to put these incremental values on the table.

If so, you can manipulate row numbers with arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (@start + @increment * (row_number() over (partition by (id - 1) / grp order by id) - 1) ) as val
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             cast(1 + round((@end - @start) / @increment, 0) as int) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

The subquery calculates a sequential number and the size of the grp.  The outer query partitions the row number and then does the arithmetic.

Basically the same idea can be done as:

```
select t.*,
       (@start + @increment * (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % cast(1 + round((@end - @start) / @increment, 0) as int))
from t;
```

But that arithmetic is a little inscrutable.

Comment: Gordon.. this won't generate more than 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for a solution to update a field on a table. You can do it with a variable as follows.

You need to write update interval to `WHERE` condition.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Id INT, TempColumn FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @Tbl (Id)
VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4)    

DECLARE @Inc FLOAT = 0 

UPDATE @Tbl
SET TempColumn = @Inc,
    @Inc += 0.2    

SELECT * FROM @Tbl
```

Result:

```
Id          TempColumn
----------- --------------
1           0,2
2           0,4
3           0,6
4           0,8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive cte to generate the numbers as required (number of rows in the table). Then use an expression to reset the series after every 3 rows.

```
declare @start decimal(10,2)=0.06;
declare @end decimal(10,2)=0.1;
declare @increment decimal(10,2)=0.02;

with numbers(rnum) as (select 1
                       union all
                       select rnum+1
                       from numbers where rnum<100 ) 
select (rnum-1)%3*@increment+@start as col
from numbers
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/NIL43187)

As you already have the table, you can simply use row numbers from it to generate this series.

```
with rownums as (select t.*,row_number() over(order by somecol) as rnum
                 from t)
select r.*,(rnum-1)%3*@increment+@start as col
from rownums r
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll often use a Table-Valued Function to create dynamic ranges.  Often faster than the a recursive cte, and has the added benefits of being parameter driven, and easily incorporated into a sub-query, cross apply, or even a cross join as illustrated below:

**Example**

```
Declare @start float     = .06 
Declare @end float       = .10
Declare @increment float = .02

Declare @groups  int     = 3    

Select ID    = Row_Number() over (Order by A.RetSeq)
      ,Value = B.RetVal
 From  [dbo].[udf-Range-Number](1,@groups,1) A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Range-Number](@start,@end,@increment) B
 Order By 1,2
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Value
1   0.06
2   0.08
3   0.10
4   0.06
5   0.08
6   0.10
7   0.06
8   0.08
9   0.10
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Number] (@R1 money,@R2 money,@Incr money)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M) As (Select cast((@R2-@R1)/@Incr as int)),
         cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N) As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d,cte1 e,cte1 f,cte1 g,cte1 h )

    Select RetSeq=1,RetVal=@R1 Union All Select N+1,(N*@Incr)+@R1
    From   cte2   
)
-- Max 100 million observations 
-- Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Number](0,4,0.25)
```